# C : Use getopt with an option which takes an optional parameter

Tags: c, getopt

I want to make a program that takes an optional parameter `-a`, which can have an optional value 'filename'. To do this, I want to use `getopt` but I can't make `-a` taking an optional parameter.

If I pass `"a"` I can do `./my_prog -a`

If I pass `"a:"` I can do `./my_prog -a filename` // filenamen is not optional here

And if I pass `"a::"` I can do `./my_prog -a[filename]`

But is there a way to obtain the result `-a [filename]` // with filename being optional ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe what you're asking for is possible.

This is probably a good thing: what should your program do if invoked as `./my_prog -a -b` where `-b`is another option it's supposed to take? It's not obvious whether it should use `-b` as the optional filename following `-a`, or assume the filename wasn't given and treat it as an option.

I would therefore suggest reconsidering whether the behaviour you ask for is actually a good idea.